# mysqli_fetch_object returns nothing

Tags: php, mysqli

```
I try querying very simple sql statement with mysqli
"select * from area where area_pre_id=6035;"
it returns nothing.
After querying this in phpmyadmin , it returns 78 rows ....
```

PHP code is as below;

---

```
$sql = "select * from area where area_pre_id=6035;";
if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)) {
     while($obj = $result->fetch_object()){ 
        if($obj->area_local_name_th){
            $my_province = $obj->area_local_name_th . "(" . $obj->area_eng_name . ")";
        }else{
            $my_province = $obj->area_eng_name;
        }
         $line[] = array("ProvinceID"=>$obj->area_id,"ProvinceName"=>$my_province);
     }
}
```

---

Please tell me what's wrong with my code or sql statement.

Comment: but where are you outputting your values, i can't see any echo or print statements...??

Comment: echo statement is under code above.

Answer (score 0):

Your mysqli command is right.I think there is no value in your database for that particular id.

Is the datatype of that id fild integer?

If it is integer then the query is right.But if it is varchar then you have to put a single quote.

select * from area where area_pre_id='6035';

Comment: datatype is integer. after  pasting  this sql statement in phpmyadmin , there are 78 row result.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to use both procedural and OOPs concept. THat will be the issue.

Try this

Change `$result->fetch_object()` to `mysqli_fetch_object($result)`

Comment: i try changing $result->fetch_object() to mysqli_fetch_object($result). It still be the same.